# Turn off Twilio heart beat in console logs

Tags: google-chrome, logging, twilio

I have pulled the same code from work to my home computer and I am getting these heartbeat console logs which make it impossible to do my own logging. On my work computer they do not show.
Can anyone explain where to turn these off?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can't tell which Twilio SDK you are using, but the SDKs usually allow you to set a `logLevel` in a config object. Try setting `logLevel: "warn"` or `logLevel: "error"` to avoid these logs.

Alternatively, there is an input at the top of your devtools with the placeholder text that says "filter". You can use that to filter the logs you want to see in the dev tools. So if you prefix your application logging with something unique, you can filter for it.

Comment: Where do you set the loglevel?

Comment: What SDK are you using here?

Comment: Twilio Video SDK

Comment: `Video.connect(token, { logLevel: "off" })`. You can see [all of the options you can pass to `connect` in the documentation](https://sdk.twilio.com/js/video/releases/2.18.1/docs/global.html#ConnectOptions)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I am using the same code base on 2 different computers so would think it's a chrome setting and not a twilio one.

Comment: Have you tried filtering the logs in the devtools instead?